# Product measure space generated by two sigma finite measure spaces

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification

Suppose we have sigma finite measure spaces $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$, $(Y,\mathcal{M},\nu)$. Let $X_j$, $Y_j$ be the exhausting sequences for $X,Y$. We know that given two measure spaces, we can generate the product measure space $(X_j \times Y_j, (\mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{N}), (\mu\times\nu)$. As $(X_j \times Y_j) \subset \mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{N}$, we can deduce that the restriction, $(X_j \times Y_j, (\mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{N}) \cap (X_j \times Y_j), (\mu\times\nu)_{(X_j \times Y_j)}(\cdot))$, is a measure space. Similarly, we deal with restricted measure spaces $(X_j, \mathcal{M} \cap X_j, \mu_{X_j}(\cdot) = \mu(\cdot \cap X_j))$, $(Y_j, \mathcal{N} \cap Y_j, \nu_{Y_j}(\cdot) = \mu(\cdot \cap Y_j))$ where $\mu_{X_j}$ is the restriction of $\mu$ to $X_j$, and same for $\nu$.

Prove that the measure space generated from these two measure spaces, $(X_i\times Y_i,(\mathcal{M} \cap X_j) \otimes (\mathcal{N} \cap Y_j), (\mu_{X_j} \times \nu_{Y_j}))$,  is equal to $(X_j \times Y_j, (\mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{N}) \cap (X_j \times Y_j), (\mu\times\nu)_{(X_j \times Y_j)}(\cdot))$. I feel like this should be easy, but I am having difficulty. Does anyone know how to prove this? Here is my attempt:

(Attempted proof) I claim $(\mathcal{M} \cap X_j) \otimes (\mathcal{N} \cap Y_j) \subset \mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{N} \cap (X_j \times Y_j)$. Due to results we proved for product measures, we know that $(\mathcal{M} \cap X_j) \otimes (\mathcal{N} \cap Y_j)$ is generated by sets of form $A \times B$, where $A \in \mathcal{M} \cap X_j$  and $B \in \mathcal{N} \cap Y_j$. Thus, $\exists A_1 \in \mathcal{M}$, $\exists B_1 \in \mathcal{N}$ such that $A = A_1 \cap X_j$, $B = B_1 \cap Y_j$. Note that $A_1 \cap X_j \times B_1 \cap Y_j = (A_1 \times B_1) \cap (X_j \times Y_j)$. This is an element of $\mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{N} \cap (X_j \times Y_j)$.

Secondly, I claim that $(\mathcal{M} \cap X_j) \otimes (\mathcal{N} \cap Y_j) \supset \mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{N} \cap (X_j \times Y_j)$. As the basis for $\mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{N}$ are sets of form $A_1 \times B_1$, where $A_1 \in \mathcal{M}$ and $B_1 \in \mathcal{N}$ ... Actually, it is not so obvious that the basis for $\mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{N} \cap (X_j \times Y_j)$ are sets of form $(A \times B) \cap (X_j \times Y_j)$ where $A \in \mathcal{M}$, $B \in \mathcal{N}$. Anyhow, I cannot think of how to prove this. Help?

Comment: I think you want $X_i, Y_i$ to be measurable to start with.  Otherwise you can't restrict the measure to a measure.

Comment: @user10354138 Yes, that is correct; that is included in the definition of 'exhausting set' that I am using.

Comment: Then $\mathcal{M}\otimes\mathcal{N}\vert X_i\times Y_i=(\mathcal{M}\vert X_i)\otimes(\mathcal{N}\vert Y_i)$ is clear from the construction of $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{S}$ as everything you get before time $\omega_1$ using complement and countable union of earlier sets, starting with $\mathcal{S}$ and the empty set.

Comment: I think you can use the fact (which requires proof) that if  $\mathcal M_{\alpha}$ is generated by $\{\mathcal E_{\alpha}:\ \alpha\in \Lambda\}$, then  $\bigotimes \mathcal M_{\alpha}:=\{\pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(E_{\alpha}):\alpha\in \Lambda ,\ E_{\alpha}\in \mathcal E_{\alpha}\}$, where $\pi_{\alpha}$ is projection on the $\alpha$-th coordinate. Btw, I don't think you need this for Folland's proof in your previous post.

Comment: @Matematleta Really? That was why I came up with this in the first place. I posted my attempted proof in my previous post, based on your comments. Could you help me understand why I don't need this for Folland's proof in my previous post?

Comment: @Matematleta, I think it should be that if  $\mathcal{M}_{\alpha}$ is generated by $\left\{\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}: \alpha \in \Lambda\right\}$, then
$\bigotimes \mathcal{M}_{\alpha}=\sigma(\left\{\pi_{\alpha}^{-1}\left(E_{\alpha}\right): \alpha \in \Lambda, E_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{E}_{\alpha}\right\}),$ where $\pi_{\alpha}$ is projection on the $\alpha$ -th coordinate? This is the proposition in Folland. Though I'm not sure how I can use this to get past the part where I am stuck in the proposed proof for this problem.

Comment: @user10354138, I don't know if that would be sufficient enough. I'm not sure which axiomatic model you're following. I agree that the sigma algebra is defined by taking intersections of all sets satisfying the sigma algebra requirements. (Therefore, we work with the **existence** of a sigma algebra; one such existence is the model generated before time $\omega_1$, as you put it.) Apart from stating that the required conclusion is 'clear', I am unsure how to justify it.

Comment: @XitaMeyers I'm using transfinite induction (or recursion) to actually construct the sigma-algebra generated by a set from the ground up (by successively adding sets into our collections): $\mathcal{S}_0=\mathcal{S}\cup\{\varnothing\}$, $\mathcal{S}_{\alpha+1}=\mathcal{S}_\alpha\cup\{\bigcap S_i\mid S_i\in\mathcal{S}_\alpha\}\cup\{S^c\mid S\in\mathcal{S}_\alpha\}$ and for nonzero limit ordinal $\alpha$ we define $\mathcal{S}_\alpha=\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}\mathcal{S}_\beta$.  Then $\sigma(\mathcal{S})=\mathcal{S}_{\omega_1}$.

Comment: If our two $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{M}\otimes\mathcal{N}\vert X_i\times Y_i$ and $(\mathcal{M}\vert X_i)\otimes(\mathcal{N}\vert Y_i)$ are not equal, then there is an earliest time $\alpha$ for which an element of the symmetric difference is born, either as $((\mathcal{M}\vert X_i)\times(\mathcal{N}\vert Y_i))_\alpha$ or as some $E\cap (X_i\times Y_i)$ with $E\in(\mathcal{M}\times\mathcal{N})_\alpha$.

Comment: Since we start at time $0$ with the same sets when restricted to $X_i\times Y_i$, and new sets can only be born on successor ordinal time, $\alpha=\beta+1$ for some ordinal $\beta$ and this set is either complement, or countable union of sets born on or before time $\beta$, but that is a contradiction because everything born on time $\beta$ would be common to both and countable sup of countable ordinals is countable, add two more steps if you need to take intersection with $X_i\times Y_i$ by De Morgan and still countable.